# Can not pass html array to JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi I'm having trouble sending html form array to JS. I have dynamic html form and some fields:

```
<div id="fields">
<input type="text" name="ppav[]" id="p" />
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="q" size="3" />
<input type="text" name="price[]" id="pr" size="10" />
<input type="text" name="sum" id="su" size="10" disabled="disabled"/>
<br />
</div>
```

in JS i tried using this function but getting `undefined` alert instead of result:

```
var welements = document.getElementsByName('ppav[]');
for (var i = 0, j = welements.length; i < j; i++) {
    var an_element = welements[i];
    alert(an_element.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pull  `selectedIndex` from a text input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What did you expect? the `selectedIndex` property returns the index of the selected option in a select element. If you want the value of your input fields, try `alert(an_element.value);`